# Run routine asynchrnously even execution is hold in child thread?

Tags: c#

I'am working on an UDP listener windows application, once an UDP message reach the application i create a new dedicated thread which do a routine relatred to this udp message.

This routine is called asynchrnously.

Why asynch ?

mainly to keep the order in wich the UDP are coming , since asynchronous call are queued in threadpool (not the case if i let each thread run synch).

My questions :

- Is it a good idea to run a routine asynchronously even this routine run in a child thread ?
- if yes, shall i implement IsBusy best pratice for this asynch call, even it's a fire and forget pattern ?

I hope i am explianing well what i wanna achieve

Apologize for my bad english

Regards

xPridex

N.B : this not the accurate code i have delete lot of details with regard to lisibity.

```
/// <summary>
/// Launch SendNotificationToEBSECW treatment.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">object : UDPmsg_t_Mapping</param>
private void StartPrepared(object sender)
{
            mainThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(EntryPointV3));
            mainThread.Start(sender);
}

private readonly object _sync = new object();
private bool _myTaskIsRunning = false;

public bool IsBusy
{
  get { return _myTaskIsRunning; }
}


public void DoWorkAsynch(Tuple.Create(x,y))
{
  MyTaskWorkerDelegate worker = new MyTaskWorkerDelegate(EntryPointV3);
  AsyncCallback completedCallback = new AsyncCallback(MyTaskCompletedCallback);

  lock (_sync)
  {
    if (_myTaskIsRunning)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("currently busy.");

    AsyncOperation async = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
    worker.BeginInvoke(Tuple.Create(x,y), completedCallback, async);
    _myTaskIsRunning = true;
  }
}

private void MyTaskCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  // get the original worker delegate and the AsyncOperation instance
  MyTaskWorkerDelegate worker =
    (MyTaskWorkerDelegate)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
  AsyncOperation async = (AsyncOperation)ar.AsyncState;

  // finish the asynchronous operation
  worker.EndInvoke(ar);

  // clear the running task flag
  lock (_sync)
  {
    _myTaskIsRunning = false;
  } 

  // raise the completed event
  AsyncCompletedEventArgs completedArgs = new AsyncCompletedEventArgs(null,
    false, null);
  async.PostOperationCompleted(
    delegate(object e) { OnMyTaskCompleted((AsyncCompletedEventArgs)e); },
    completedArgs);
}

public event AsyncCompletedEventHandler MyTaskCompleted;

protected virtual void OnMyTaskCompleted(AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (MyTaskCompleted != null)
    MyTaskCompleted(this, e);
}
```

Comment: Please show us how you "create a new dedicated thread" and how you "call" it.

Comment: i just update the post to add code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing obviously wrong with that code, but I do have a few comments:

- `new Thread` does not use the thread pool, it always creates a new dedicated thread.
- Neither creating a new dedicated thread nor using the thread pool will ensure threads are completed in order due to thread scheduling, the work done, and other things outside your control.

If you must handle the messages in the order they are received, you should not handle each message in a separate thread. Instead, add each message to a queue and process each item in the queue sequentially in a background thread.

Threads do not have any built-in way of alerting their creator when they are done, or returning results. If you want to do that, use `System.MulticastDelegate.BeginInvoke`; that uses the thread pool. If you want intermediate results while the thread runs, use `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: many thanks Dour High Arch for the deep explanations, now i got it